# How to draw this window?

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk, pygtk

Can I create a window without this topbar? :

[image: http://i52.tinypic.com/2e30dpi.png]

I want a window like this:

[image: http://i52.tinypic.com/1q62pg.jpg]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwindow.html#method-gtkwindow--set-decorated) they say you could try:

```
gtk.Window.set_decorated(False)
```

Comment: The rounded corners depend on your user's GTK settings. This command just removes as much decoration as possible.

Comment: Yeah, actually the rounded corners _are_ decoration.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do

```
window.set_type_hint(gtk.gdk.WINDOW_TYPE_HINT_SPLASHSCREEN)
```

but that doesn't have rounded corners either, at least on my theme. As eumiro says, that depends on the theme settings.